# OneDrive Service Ends when I Exit Terminal

Tags: 22.04

I have run OneDrive with Kubuntu 18.04 and Cinnamon Mint 20.3 using ppa:yann1ck/onedrive, which was excellent and maybe perfect.

I installed a new Ubuntu 22.04 and research said not to use the yann1ck ppa, but to use an OpenSuSE debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 distribution.

I did a one-time onedrive --synchronize  and now I want to monitor with, onedrive --monitor. When I close the terminal window, the onedrive service stops. I learned how to move the process to the background by ctrl+z and bg, but the process still stops when I exit the terminal.

What I expect is for the onedrive service to run when I am logged in and to monitor for changes every 5 minutes and update files as necessary,  which is how the yann1ck ppa worked.

Is there a way for this to work like the old way? I am not a sophisticated linux user, so I need precise instructions.

Thank you, Kevin

Comment: Try opening an issue at https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues

Comment: Opening an issue is only for 'bugs' and/or 'feature requests'. A better pointer for help would be to open a new discussion as this is why https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions exists for this type of question

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Archisman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> I have run OneDrive with Kubuntu 18.04 and Cinnamon Mint 20.3 using ppa:yann1ck/onedrive, which was excellent and maybe perfect

The PPA was depreciated in July 2021. It should never have been used for Kubuntu 18.04 and Cinnamon Mint 20.3 beyond that date as the client you were using would never have been correctly updated to the latest code. You were putting yourself at risk of data loss by using that PPA due to the client version the PPA provided.

The correct way to install the client on any Ubuntu platform or a platform based on Ubuntu is to follow https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

> I did a one-time onedrive --synchronize and now I want to monitor with, onedrive --monitor. When I close the terminal window, the onedrive service stops. I learned how to move the process to the background by ctrl+z and bg, but the process still stops when I exit the terminal.

The PPA contained a systemd bug, where a duplicate systemd service was installed so that the client automatically started when it was authenticated. See: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/1274

This was fixed by the OpenSuSE packages.

> Is there a way for this to work like the old way? I am not a sophisticated linux user, so I need precise instructions.

Please refer to the GitHub repository documents here https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/tree/master/docs - specifically https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md

The section you want to read is: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#onedrive-service-running-as-a-non-root-user-via-systemd-with-notifications-enabled-arch-ubuntu-debian-opensuse-fedora

This will give you the commands you run as your 'normal user' (assuming here that it is your normal user account that you authenticated the client as):

```
systemctl --user enable onedrive
systemctl --user start onedrive
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the document I followed,and I read the systemctl comments but did not clue in that I needed to run those. This is a correct answer and now the services are running whenever I log in.

Comment: @imalinuxflubadub Good to hear you got it resolved with the help of abraunegg's answer.  Please do click the "Checkmark" next to the answer to Accept it when you get a moment.  Note that after accepting, you can also click the "Flag" icon next to *this* (my) comment here and ask that it be removed as "No longer needed".  Thanks!